# Make asp.net webpage respond to WebClient request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have run into a problem in my asp.net and vb.net programming. I have made a website which connects to a database to authenticate users. I have made another page which my windows form application uses to authenticate users so the program does not have to connect directly to the MySql Database as this is insecure.

So far, the code for my asp.net page is:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Request.QueryString.Keys(0) = "key" And Request.QueryString.Keys(1) = "getapikeyv1" And Request.QueryString.Keys(2) = "authapienc2" Then
            Dim key As String = Request.QueryString.Get("key")
            If key = "dua9r3rqpK{WPDWp9r93af03r8yqrEPIF{A}W~DW)D08q3raewdawdug9q8wdyaw9wq" Then
                returnLabel.Text = "XYeJay4XVh6amvf1kJ34Y6y6hR0sSokP9oJFsi0Mxl4QB0T86W0iac9o2nRfCmFmsONq6sPz+rdX+/NqFk3inHRGnwnqf0IsQXE/M/SvnvY="
            Else
                returnLabel.Text = "invk"
            End If
        Else
            returnLabel.Text = "invalidrequest"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The default value for 'returnLabel' is INVALIDREQUEST. My api keys defined above are working fine so are not needed to be considered here. However, when I use the following code to communicate with the webpage, it always returns with returnLabel's value as 'INVALIDREQUEST'. Even if I put the returnLabel.Text = "1233" at the beginning of the Me.Load sub, the page still returns INVALIDREQUEST when I communicate with it through my program!

I use this code to request:

```
        Try
        Dim APIRequest As New WebClient
        APIRequest.QueryString.Add("key", r9j0wqfha0fh0wf0.DecryptString128Bit(APIKey5, dVadaihwdq93ra0w0))
        APIRequest.QueryString.Add("getapikeyv1", "")
        APIRequest.QueryString.Add("authapienc2", "")
        Dim ako39rqwfa As String = APIRequest.DownloadString(EncryptionPageUrl)
        MsgBox(ako39rqwfa)
        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(ako39rqwfa, "<span id=""returnLabel"">.*?</span>")
        APIKey00 = m.Value.Replace("<span id=""returnLabel"">", "").Replace("</span>", "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

As you can see, the WebClient I use is fine but the Me.Load sub in the webpage is not responding the request made by the program...

Is there any way I can make the webpage respond to the WebClient.DownloadString() function?

Thanks,

Rodit

(ps. c# or vb code would be appreciated)

Comment: Instead of trying to hack this into an .aspx page response, I'd suggest using a technology made for this, such as webapi, wcf, serviestack, etc

Comment: What happens when you type the URL into a browser?

Comment: @iamkrillin I need a solution not an alternative... But thanks for the swift reply

Comment: @RickS returns INVALIDREQUEST

Comment: You enter the URL AND the querystring into your browser and you still get INVALIDREQUEST?

Comment: @RickS yep... i put encryption.aspx?key=MYAPIKEY&getapikeyv1=ef&authapienc2=wejaw

Comment: Must be how you are checking the querystring..check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your asp.net page to check the query string like this, not sure if you can assume they are in a certain order:

```
If Request.QueryString.Get("key") isnot nothing  And 
Request.QueryString.Get("getapikeyv1") isnot nothing  And 
Request.QueryString.Get("authapienc2") isnot nothing  Then
```

Comment: This does not work either. I am sure it is something to do with the asp page not responding to my WebClient as even if I change returnLabel.Text outside of the if clause, it still says INVALIDREQUEST...

Comment: But doing the call in the browser should work.  So it's your asp.net code if you get the same result in the browser.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your code and debug it.  You'll know the issue right away.